# cut text in PHP

Tags: php, html

i have for example:

```
$one =
aaaa
bbbbb
cccc
dddd
eeeee
dsfas
fsadf
asdf;
```

i would like return all for eeeee:

$two = somefunction($one);

echo $two =

```
eeeee
dsfas
fsadf
asdf;
```

thanks for help!

$one and $two are string!

Comment: That's too generic ... what are your rules for cutting text?

Comment: Is `$one` an array, a string or what? And do you want to return all [elements] after `eeeee` inclusive, or have I misunderstood your (rather poor) question?

Comment: Are you talking about storing $one as an array `['aaaa','bbbb']` or as a single string 'aaaaa bbbb'? You want all results after 'eeeee' correct? If you're a bit more clear on what you want we can answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a million ways to do this, but for doing exactly what you describe. [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) is probably simplest:

```
$two = strstr($one,'eeeee');
```

If you can give us more of a real-world example, we might recommend somthing else...